# Text nodes are not unmarshalled for combination @XmlMixed + @XmlElementRefs + @XmlElementWrapper

Tags: jaxb

I have the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "any-text")
public class AnyText {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "fixed-text", required = true)
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "year", namespace = "http://foo.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "title", namespace = "http://foo.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> fixedText = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
...
```

which is supposed to represent the following XML:

```
<any-text xmlns="http://foo.org/">
    <fixed-text>The story <title>Alice in Wonderland</title> was printed in <year>1865</year>.</fixed-text>
</any-text>
```

However when I unmarshall and marshall this XML, I get this:

```
<any-text xmlns="http://foo.org/">
    <fixed-text>
        <title>Alice in Wonderland</title>
        <year>1865</year>
    </fixed-text>
</any-text>
```

basically all text nodes are gone. I checked the memory model and found out that they are not unmarshalled. When I try to add text nodes programatically and marshall the model, text nodes still do not appear. Any workaround is appreciated.

I am using JAXB v2.2.4, but I tested also v2.2.8 with no success.

This issue is very similar (perhaps identical) to one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940577/unmarshalling-xmlmixed-string-list) and I have also reported it as [JAXB-1107](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1107).

Comment: I can confirm that this is also the case when `@XmlMixed`/`@XmlElementWrapper`/`@XmlAnyElement` are placed on the same property.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the JAXB implementation.

The work around is to split your JAXB entity class into two.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "any-text")
public class AnyText {

    @XmlElement(name = "fixed-text", required = true)
    protected FixedText fixedText;

...
}

public class FixedText {
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(
            name = "year", 
            namespace = "http://foo.org/", 
            type = JAXBElement.class, 
            required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(
            name = "title", 
            namespace = "http://foo.org/", 
            type = JAXBElement.class, 
            required = false)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> fixedText = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
}
```